# WinCVS - How deselect automatic 'Graph'

Tags: wincvs

I have a little problem with my WinCVS. 
When I right-click on a file, I can click on 'Graph'.

Now previeus it showed a dialogbox where I could select info and click on the 'OK' button.

The problem is that I vinked on something before I clicked on 'OK' and now when I right-click on 
'Graph' I get the graph righ away.

But how do I get that Dialog box back?

I hope people understand my problem, as I find it hard to explain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know the answer, I needed to hold down the [shift] key when doing 'right-click', 'graph'.